# Ao usar jQuery append exibe o texto [object Object] e não insere a elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

Criei uma div.box no html e nela quero inserir uma outra div que crio na execução do código, segue o avaixo:

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

JS:

```
var item = $('<div />', {class: 'item'})
var box = $('.box')

box.on('click', function (e) {
  this.append(item)
})
```

Porém ao inves de aparecer a div.item dentro de div.box aparece o texto [object Object]. Percebi que isso só acontece quando executado no evento de click, fazendo da forma abaixo funciona:

```
var item = $('<div />', {class: 'item'})
var box = $('.box')
box.append(item)
```

Alguém tem uma explicação para isso?

Comment: Quando tu usa o `this` dentro do `.on()` ocorre o erro, mas e se tu mudar para `box.apend(item);` dentro do `.on()` o erro persiste?

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta, mas uma outra coisa que se pode fazer no lugar de usar append é concatenar os innerHTML dos elementos com o que estava antes + o conteúdo novo - Este não é o modo mais eficiente, mas algumas vezes é o mais simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao usar o `this` você está usando um objeto do **JavaScript Puro** que não têm as implementações do JQuery, para corrigir basta dar 1 cast no `this`

```
box.on('click', function (e) {
  $(this).append(item)
})
```

Se você der um console.log no `this` e no `$(this)` verá que o `$(this)` tem várias propriedades a mais que o `this` nativo.

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo. Bobeada minha. Sua resposta foi escolhida pois teve a explicação do cast.

Answer (score 3):

Faltou colocar o `this` "dentro" do jquery `$(this)`, la no seu click.

So dei uma modificada pra voce ver funcionando.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  var item = $('<div>NOVO TEXTO</div>');
  var box = $('.box');

  box.on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).append(item)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">TEXTO</div>
```

Comment: Neuber, gostei da sua resposta(+1). Só uma pergunta: Porque se eu clicar de novo não adiciona NOVO TEXTO mais uma vez em baixo?

Comment: Te falo q verdade que nao sei o motivo exato, mas se colocar a variavel item `var item = $('<div>NOVO TEXTO</div>');` dentro do click, antes do `append` funciona com certeza. La vai chute mas pode ser pra nao colocar objeto repetido, quando usa o `$('...')` acredito que o jquery cria uma nova "instancia" para esse elemento, e talvez ele saiba que ja deu append com aquela instancia. Quando esta dentro do click é sempre uma nova instancia, ou talvez não tenha absolutamente nada a ver com isso que falei.

Comment: Tbém percebi isso, só adiciona uma vez.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira o que vc escreveu faz sentido. Deve ser por isso mesmo. De qualquer forma se colocando dentro do bloco do onclick tb resolve, no dia que for necessário fica tranquilo tb. Ex: se fosse o caso de existir necessidade que o conteúdo seja passado fora desse bloco poderia ser até  var itemcontent = '<div>NOVO TEXTO</div>'; fora do bloco do onclick e $(this).append($(itemcontent)) dentro do bloco do onclick.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Só vai uma vez pq o "novo texto" esta numa váriavel e toda vez que você clica ele pega a mesma div com o "novo texto" e coloca no mesmo lugar se mudar o código para _$(this).append(item.clone())_ ele insere várias vezes...